# How to check the internet connection in react native

Tags: react-native

I m working on react native project, I m using @react-native-community/netinfo package to check the internet status. It will work to me, but I have a doubt, if a person using internet connection with wifi, but the wifi device does not connect to the internet, then how to find that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

useEffect(() => {
const removeNetInfoSubscription = NetInfo.addEventListener((state)={

const offline = !(state.isConnected && state.isInternetReachable);

console.log(offline);

});

return () => removeNetInfoSubscription();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isInternetReachable` to check that.
Here's a working code snippet that I'm using in my projects.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      console.log('Connection type', state.type)
      console.log('Is Internet Reachable?', state.isInternetReachable)
      if (connected !== state.isInternetReachable)
        setConnected(state.isInternetReachable)
    })
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [connected])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this question is all over stackoverflow and no one seems to look at other existing answers.

You should use the "@react-native-community/netinfo" library. NetInfo used to be part of the react-native, but then it got separated out of the core. If you want to observe network state changes just use the provided addEventListener method.

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    console.log("Is reachable?", state. isInternetReachable);
});

const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    console.log("Is reachable?", state. isInternetReachable);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```